# Django - how to dynamically display image from outside source

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have been struggling for hours and cant find any answers or solutions for how to get this to work

In django views I generate a variable which is an image source from another website (mainurl='https://i.etsystatic.com/8413186/r/il/57b06e/1918667731/il_570xN.1918667731_asje.jpg')

I render my page as follows

```
return render(request,'app/listingresults.html',{"mainurl":mainurl})
```

I cant get the below code to work

```html
<img src={{  mainurl  }}>
```

If i enter the URL directly to test it works fine

```html
<img src='https://i.etsystatic.com/8413186/r/il/57b06e/1918667731/il_570xN.1918667731_asje.jpg'>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="{{  mainurl  }}">
```

Or this:

```
<img src='{{  mainurl  }}'>
```

Basically, you need to add `"` or `'` before `{{` and after `}}`.